# How to get days between current date and other date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying this sql.

```
select a.id,b.d_date,a.bp_date,DATEDIFF('day',now()-b.d_date) from imp a inner join dp b
on a.id = b.id where a.bp_date is null
```

but it gives me null value.

Comment: `current_date - b.disbursement_date` see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Comment: it gives me this value -20210093880597.643000

Comment: What is the data type of `b.d_date`?  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: 2020-12-30 16:19:29.712000 this is the format and the data type is datetime in postgresql.

Comment: There is no data type "datetime" in Postgres

Comment: it is timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
select current_date - '2020-12-30 16:19:29.712000'::date;
 ?column? 
----------
      180
(1 row)
```